# How to get the column count from an empty collection of type EnumerableRowCollection

Tags: c#

I have an object of type `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>` which doesn't have any items in it. How can I get the number of columns in it?

I can use the IDE to dig through the properties to get the count but I don't know how to get this via code. In the image you can see the source table has 2 columns.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, as far as I'm aware.

The fact that an `EnumerableRowCollection` is backed by a `DataTable` is an implementation detail. It's *logically* just a sequence of `DataRow`s, and an empty sequence logically doesn't have a number of columns.

If you need this information, it sounds like you ought to be retaining a reference to the source `DataTable` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the info using private reflection, if you really need to. Probably it is better to keep a reference to the original DataTable.